# Pandas apply function running slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function that given an id, a number n and a dataframe returns the nth element on column "something" where the "id" is the id in the params.

```
def find_something(id,n,df):
  table = df.loc[(df['id'] == id)]
  try:
      something = df['something'].iloc[n-1]
  except:
      something = float('NaN')
  return something
```

When I run this for 1 id (the id is of format np.int32 and the df in the params has 20 million rows) it runs in 11.4 ns, but when I apply it to a dataframe column with 60K rows it takes hours to run:

```
my_table['new_column'] = my_table['id'].apply(find_something, args=(1,df,))
```

So if I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2, 2, 2,
                          2,1,2,2],
                   'something' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

And:

```
my_table = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2]})

my_table['new_column'] = my_table['id'].apply(find_something, args=(1,df,))
```

my_table should look like:

```
    id  new_column
0   1   -0.396238
1   2    0.074007
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I don't see any reason why for 1 element it takes 11 ns but for 60K it takes hours.

Comment: You can do this without apply. Can you provide a [mcve] with sample data and expected output? Would help.

Comment: Yes, I think you can do that using a straight boolean operation and not use a function.   Please provide data and expected results.

Comment: Edited with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Are you planning on going over all values of `id` that are in the `df` variable? or only selected ones? Also what is `n`?

Answer (score 1):

I generated a similar dataset with 20 million rows and 60K IDs and ran it through your code; it took about an hour to finish. Generally, user-defined functions suffer from the lack of speed as `apply()` does not take advantage of Pandas’ vectorization. If executing `apply()` with large datasets is a major pain point for you, you should consider alternative solutions such as Bodo. I ran the same code through Bodo; it only took about **1.5 minutes** to finish. Essentially, Bodo optimizes your `apply()` code to maintain the vectorization provided while providing access to scientifically correct parallelization methods. The community edition of Bodo enables you to run on up to 4 cores. Here is a link to the installation page: https://docs.bodo.ai/latest/source/install.html

```
#data generation

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : np.random.randint(1,60000,20000000),
                   'something' : np.random.randn(20000000)})
my_table = pd.DataFrame({'id' : np.arange(1, 60000)})

my_table.to_parquet("table.pq")
df.to_parquet("df.pq")
```

With Pandas (I did some minor changes in your code to make it more robust):

```
def find_something(id,n,df):
    df = df.loc[(df['id'] == id)]
    if len(df) != 0:
        result = df['something'].iloc[n-1]
    else:
        result = np.nan
    return result

start = time.time()

df = pd.read_parquet("df.pq")
my_table = pd.read_parquet("table.pq")
my_table['new_column'] = my_table['id'].apply(find_something, args=(1,df,))

end = time.time()
print("computation time: ", end - start)

print(my_table.head())

output:
computation time:  3482.743801832199
   id  new_column
0   1   -1.096224
1   2    0.667792
2   3    1.069627
3   4    0.129955
4   5    0.150882
```

With Bodo:

```
%%px

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import bodo

@bodo.jit(distributed = ['df', 'result'])
def find_something(id,n,df):
    df = df.loc[(df['id'] == id)]
    if len(df) != 0:
        result = df['something'].iloc[n-1]
    else:
        result = np.nan
    return result

@bodo.jit(distributed = ['my_table', 'df'])
def new_column():
    start = time.time()
    df = pd.read_parquet("df.pq")
    my_table = pd.read_parquet("table.pq")
    my_table['new_column'] = my_table['id'].apply(find_something, args=(1,df,))
    end = time.time()
    print("computation time: ", end - start)
    print(my_table.head())
    return my_table
    
my_table = new_column()

output:
[stdout:0] 
computation time:  103.9169020652771
 id  new_column
0   1   -1.096224
1   2    0.667792
2   3    1.069627
3   4    0.129955
4   5    0.150882
```

Disclaimer: I work as a data scientist advocate in Bodo.ai.

Comment: Seems interesting! how does it(bodo) works? I'm assuming it is not compiling directly to the native code as in case of numba, correct?

Comment: Bodo uses Numba/LLVM under the hoods to generate native code actually (after optimization, parallelization, etc. is done).

Comment: Cool. I'll definitely check it out.